# show magento scope switcher in admin grid edit form

Tags: magento-1.8, adminform, scope-switcher

I'm working on a module in magento admin where I would like to show the `scope selector` as in manage products, manage categories, system configuration for my grid edit form.

![screenshot][1]

Can anyone help me how could I add that and `store values in database specific to the scope selected`?

**Update**
`saveAction()` from adminhtml controller

```
public function saveAction() {
    if ($data = $this->getRequest()->getPost()) {

        if (isset($_FILES['smalllogo']['name']) && $_FILES['smalllogo']['name'] != '') {
            try {
                /* Starting upload */
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('smalllogo');

                // Any extention would work
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                // Set the file upload mode
                // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                // true -> get the file in the product like folders
                //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                // We set media as the upload dir
                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
                $logo = $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['smalllogo']['name']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

            // $mediaPath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $data['smalllogo'] = $logo['file']; //$_FILES['smalllogo']['name']; //$mediaPath . $_FILES['smalllogo']['name'];
        } else if (isset($data['smalllogo']['delete']) && $data['smalllogo']['delete'] == 1) {
            unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $data['smalllogo']['value']);
            $data['smalllogo'] = '';
        } else {
            unset($data['smalllogo']);
        }

        if (isset($_FILES['banner']['name']) && $_FILES['banner']['name'] != '') {
            try {
                /* Starting upload */
                $uploader = new Varien_File_Uploader('banner');

                // Any extention would work
                $uploader->setAllowedExtensions(array('jpg', 'jpeg', 'gif', 'png'));
                $uploader->setAllowRenameFiles(false);

                // Set the file upload mode
                // false -> get the file directly in the specified folder
                // true -> get the file in the product like folders
                //  (file.jpg will go in something like /media/f/i/file.jpg)
                $uploader->setFilesDispersion(false);

                $path = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS;
                $banner = $uploader->save($path, $_FILES['banner']['name']);
            } catch (Exception $e) {

            }

            // $mediaPath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);
            $data['banner'] = $banner['file']; //$_FILES['banner']['name']; //$mediaPath . $_FILES['banner']['name'];
        } else if (isset($data['banner']['delete']) && $data['banner']['delete'] == 1) {
            unlink(Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . $data['banner']['value']);
            $data['banner'] = '';
        } else {
            unset($data['banner']);
        }


        $model = Mage::getModel('designer/designer');
        $model->setData($data)
                ->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));

        try {
            if ($model->getCreatedTime == NULL || $model->getUpdateTime() == NULL) {
                $model->setCreatedTime(now())
                        ->setUpdateTime(now());
            } else {
                $model->setUpdateTime(now());
            }

            $model->save();
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addSuccess(Mage::helper('designer')->__('Designer was successfully saved'));
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData(false);

            if ($this->getRequest()->getParam('back')) {
                $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $model->getId()));
                return;
            }
            $this->_redirect('*/*/');
            return;
        } catch (Exception $e) {
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError($e->getMessage());
            Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->setFormData($data);
            $this->_redirect('*/*/edit', array('id' => $this->getRequest()->getParam('id')));
            return;
        }
    }
    Mage::getSingleton('adminhtml/session')->addError(Mage::helper('designer')->__('Unable to find designer to save'));
    $this->_redirect('*/*/');
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add this to the layout handle for the add/edit page:

```
<reference name="left">
    <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" before="-" />
    <!-- add other blocks if you have in here -->
</reference>
```

**[EDIT]**
If your models extend the EAV models you can save the values for a specific store by replacing

```
$model->setData($data)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

with

```
$storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
$model->setData($data)->setStoreId($storeId)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));
```

Comment: but how would I be able to save the selected scope in database so that the saved record will be visible only in that particular store or website

Comment: also, If I do change the scope it shows me an alert message. but in case of magento's default modules it do not show any alert

Comment: Let me get the big picture strait. You are trying to build a module that should contain an EAV entity. One that behaves as the products and categories, right?

Comment: exactly. you are right. Could you please help me with that?

Comment: This may not solve your problem, but It can help you kick start you extension. You can give this tool a try: https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9. It's a module creator that can also create EAV entities. It is still under development, but it seams to work OK for simple EAV entities. It still has some issues with the API files (if you need an API for your entity) but I'm working on it. Anyway, even if it has a few more bugs in it, you can at least start your module with it and just change something here and there.

Comment: will it work with this store switcher? because my module is already working. so if you can suggest any change do I need to make in order to get those records saved based on the scope

Comment: You can test it first. Create a simple module and see if it fits your needs.  As for saving the values, it depends a lot on how your controller looks like. Post the `saveAction` of your controller in the question.

Comment: updated the question with save action

Comment: I'd seen your edit and seems to be helpful. but still a problem that value **0** is stored in database for store. Not getting why? even the value is being passed in url

Comment: make sure the param name is correct. It may not be 'store'. Maybe it's `store_id`. Also make sure that the action of the form you submit has the store or store_id parameter in it.

Comment: I'm sure. the parameter name is **store**. On change the url looks like `magento/index.php/designer/adminhtml_designer/edit/id/1/key/3098118acf3ac58e1735dbbc5774d0b6/store/4/`

Comment: Yes...but when you submit the form? It should be `magento/index.php/designer/adminhtml_designer/save/id/1/key/{some key here}/store/4/`

Comment: I think this one is related to my question: http://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/17193/is-it-possible-to-save-attribute-value-per-store-in-custom-eav-based-model I think it can't be done by default.