# Is it possible to save attribute value per store in custom eav based model?

Tags: attributes, model, eav

Let's say I have custom EAV entity type with it's tables that have store field (just like catalog/product tables have). Can default EAV resource model save data per store? From what I have seen, in Mage_Eav_Model_Entity_Abstract there is _saveAttribute method (which is used for inserting and updating) which does not create store_id key:

```
protected function _saveAttribute($object, $attribute, $value)
{
    $table = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();
    if (!isset($this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table])) {
        $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table] = array();
    }

    $entityIdField = $attribute->getBackend()->getEntityIdField();

    $data   = array(
        'entity_type_id'    => $object->getEntityTypeId(),
        $entityIdField      => $object->getId(),
        'attribute_id'      => $attribute->getId(),
        'store_id'          => $object->getStoreId(),
        'value'             => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
    );

    $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table][] = $data;

    return $this;
}
```

I have also seen that products use different mechanism for this (in Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract):

```
    protected function _saveAttributeValue($object, $attribute, $value)
{
    $write   = $this->_getWriteAdapter();
    $storeId = (int)Mage::app()->getStore($object->getStoreId())->getId();
    $table   = $attribute->getBackend()->getTable();

    /**
     * If we work in single store mode all values should be saved just
     * for default store id
     * In this case we clear all not default values
     */
    if (Mage::app()->isSingleStoreMode()) {
        $storeId = $this->getDefaultStoreId();
        $write->delete($table, array(
            'attribute_id = ?' => $attribute->getAttributeId(),
            'entity_id = ?'    => $object->getEntityId(),
            'store_id <> ?'    => $storeId
        ));
    }

    $data = new Varien_Object(array(
        'entity_type_id'    => $attribute->getEntityTypeId(),
        'attribute_id'      => $attribute->getAttributeId(),
        'store_id'          => $storeId,
        'entity_id'         => $object->getEntityId(),
        'value'             => $this->_prepareValueForSave($value, $attribute)
    ));
    $bind = $this->_prepareDataForTable($data, $table);

    if ($attribute->isScopeStore()) {
        /**
         * Update attribute value for store
         */
        $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table][] = $bind;
    } else if ($attribute->isScopeWebsite() && $storeId != $this->getDefaultStoreId()) {
        /**
         * Update attribute value for website
         */
        $storeIds = Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsite()->getStoreIds(true);
        foreach ($storeIds as $storeId) {
            $bind['store_id'] = (int)$storeId;
            $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table][] = $bind;
        }
    } else {
        /**
         * Update global attribute value
         */
        $bind['store_id'] = $this->getDefaultStoreId();
        $this->_attributeValuesToSave[$table][] = $bind;
    }

    return $this;
}
```

This leads me to believe that it is impossible to make EAV based models with values per store without some overwriting. Since I have seen that people mention that it is possible to do it, I would like someone to clarify this for me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's possible.
When I create an EAV entity I make the entity model extend `Mage_Catalog_Model_Abstract`, the resource model extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Abstract`, and the resource collection model extends `Mage_Catalog_Model_Resource_Collection_Abstract`.
This way the entity behaves in a similar was to the product or category entity.

You can give [this module creator](https://github.com/tzyganu/UMC1.9) a try. It's not yet in a final stage but it should work for simple modules. It has support for creating EAV entities.

Comment: Yes I had that idea too. I just thought that that kind of approach might have some side effects when entities are not catalog related.

Comment: @LDusan I don't thing it has side effects. Those classes I mentioned are never instantiated. They are just there as a common ancestor for the product and category classes. And, as you can see the product and category are 2 very different entities. It won't hurt if you add an other one :).

Comment: @Marius - one caveat I think is that, **when adding attributes to those custom EAV entities**, the catalog resource will insert into the *catalog's specific additional tables*. I don't think OP wants that. Looking at [this article](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/creating-an-eav-based-models-in-magento/), I think you must declare your own tables in which your attribute would reside.

Comment: @nevvermind Until a few weeks ago I thought the same thing but based on the answers provided here http://magento.stackexchange.com/q/13598/146 it seams that is possible to store everything in the tables provided by Magento.

Comment: @Marius - Wow. So there's an EAV table fallback. And, yes, I was wrong actually: there's no additional table if you don't define it in `eav_entity_type` table. As for the attribute values, they seem to be going to `eav_entity_int/decimal/...` if you don't define your own. But I still don't like non-catalog EAV entities to use catalog resources.

Comment: @nevvermind. I can live with the fact that you don't like non-catalog entities using catalog resources. :). I've used that in the past and it worked perfectly. If you don't like using those classes you clone them in your own module and use the clones. This way you have a full separation and working EAV module.