# How to add Store view selector in my custom admin grid module!

Tags: magento-1.9, admin, grid

How can I add the Store view selector in my custom admin grid module![enter image description here][1]

I added this in my layout now its comming in my grid now to save store wise grid information in to database

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Essentially you need to add the xml for your layout file, e.g.:

```
        <block type="adminhtml/store_switcher" name="store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
            <action method="setUseConfirm">
                <params>0</params>
            </action>
        </block>
```

Then the usual getChildHtml in template:

```
<?php echo $this->getChildHtml('store_switcher');?>
```

Without knowing the specifics of your module and layout xml it is hard to say how that works out for you in the backend. However, see this question where @Marius explains how to pick up the store id:

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17190/12662

Comment: Thanks for reply just i did add in layout but how to save grid information store wise

Comment: Follow the link.

Comment: what i can i see on that link ?

Comment: You did visit: http://magento.stackexchange.com/a/17190/12662 ? See this `$storeId = $this->getRequest()->getParam('store', 0);
$model->setData($data)->setStoreId($storeId)->setId($this->getRequest()->getParam('id'));`

Answer (score 0):

**For versions above 2.3.0**

Update your layout as below. `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/mymodule_myproduct_grid.xml )`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="adminhtml.report.grid.store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="use_confirm" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_websites" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_groups" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_views" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="my_product_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

To filter products you need to change the UI component for the `Bookmark`.

Create a UI component class as `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/Component/Bookmark.php )`:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Component;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Api\BookmarkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Api\BookmarkRepositoryInterface;

class Bookmark extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Bookmark
{
     public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        \MyVendor\MyModule\Api\ProfileRepositoryInterface $profile,
        BookmarkRepositoryInterface $bookmarkRepository,
        BookmarkManagementInterface $bookmarkManagement,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $bookmarkRepository, $bookmarkManagement, $components, $data);
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

    /**
     * Register component
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $namespace = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('namespace', $this->getContext()->getNamespace());
        $config = [];
        if (!empty($namespace)) {
            $storeId = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('store');

            if (empty($storeId)) {
                $storeId = $this->getContext()->getFilterParam('store_id');
            }

            $bookmarks = $this->bookmarkManagement->loadByNamespace($namespace);
            /** @var \Magento\Ui\Api\Data\BookmarkInterface $bookmark */
            foreach ($bookmarks->getItems() as $bookmark) {
                if ($bookmark->isCurrent()) {
                    $config['activeIndex'] = $bookmark->getIdentifier();
                }

                $config = array_merge_recursive($config, $bookmark->getConfig());

                if (!empty($storeId)) {
                    $config['current']['filters']['applied']['store_id'] = $storeId;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->setData('config', array_replace_recursive($config, $this->getConfiguration($this)));

        parent::prepare();

        $jsConfig = $this->getConfiguration($this);
        $this->getContext()->addComponentDefinition($this->getComponentName(), $jsConfig);
    }
}
```

Add the `Bookmark` UI component in your UI grid xml `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_product_listing.xml )`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks" class="\MyVendor\MyModule\Component\Bookmark">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">my_product_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Replace: `\MyVendor\MyModule` and `my_product_listing` with your namespace.

Also there is another way of add the store selector in the grid i.e via filters same as catalog product grid.

Reference link is working to add store switcher in your custom admin page

https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/252745/90013