# How to add storeview switcher in custom admin grid which created using ui component in magento2.2.5?

Tags: magento2, multistore, uicomponent

How to add storeview code in admin grid which created using ui component.

[image]

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Update your layout as below. `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/layout/mymodule_myproduct_grid.xml )`

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<page xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
      xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:View/Layout/etc/page_configuration.xsd">
    <update handle="styles"/>
    <body>
        <referenceContainer name="page.main.actions">
            <block class="Magento\Backend\Block\Store\Switcher" name="adminhtml.report.grid.store_switcher" as="store_switcher">
                <arguments>
                    <argument name="use_confirm" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_websites" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_groups" xsi:type="string">0</argument>
                    <argument name="switch_store_views" xsi:type="string">1</argument>
                </arguments>
            </block>
        </referenceContainer>
        <referenceContainer name="content">
            <uiComponent name="my_product_listing"/>
        </referenceContainer>
    </body>
</page>
```

To filter products you need to change the UI component for the `Bookmark`.

Create a UI component class as `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/Component/Bookmark.php )`:

```
namespace MyVendor\MyModule\Component;

use Magento\Framework\View\Element\UiComponent\ContextInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Api\BookmarkManagementInterface;
use Magento\Ui\Api\BookmarkRepositoryInterface;

class Bookmark extends \Magento\Ui\Component\Bookmark
{
     public function __construct(
        ContextInterface $context,
        \MyVendor\MyModule\Api\ProfileRepositoryInterface $profile,
        BookmarkRepositoryInterface $bookmarkRepository,
        BookmarkManagementInterface $bookmarkManagement,
        array $components = [],
        array $data = []
    ) {
        parent::__construct($context, $bookmarkRepository, $bookmarkManagement, $components, $data);
        $this->profile = $profile;
    }

    /**
     * Register component
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function prepare()
    {
        $namespace = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('namespace', $this->getContext()->getNamespace());
        $config = [];
        if (!empty($namespace)) {
            $storeId = $this->getContext()->getRequestParam('store');

            if (empty($storeId)) {
                $storeId = $this->getContext()->getFilterParam('store_id');
            }

            $bookmarks = $this->bookmarkManagement->loadByNamespace($namespace);
            /** @var \Magento\Ui\Api\Data\BookmarkInterface $bookmark */
            foreach ($bookmarks->getItems() as $bookmark) {
                if ($bookmark->isCurrent()) {
                    $config['activeIndex'] = $bookmark->getIdentifier();
                }

                $config = array_merge_recursive($config, $bookmark->getConfig());

                if (!empty($storeId)) {
                    $config['current']['filters']['applied']['store_id'] = $storeId;
                }
            }
        }

        $this->setData('config', array_replace_recursive($config, $this->getConfiguration($this)));

        parent::prepare();

        $jsConfig = $this->getConfiguration($this);
        $this->getContext()->addComponentDefinition($this->getComponentName(), $jsConfig);
    }
}
```

Add the `Bookmark` UI component in your UI grid xml `(File: MyVendor/MyModule/view/adminhtml/ui_component/my_product_listing.xml )`:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<listing xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:module:Magento_Ui:etc/ui_configuration.xsd">
     <listingToolbar name="listing_top">
        <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
            <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="sticky" xsi:type="boolean">true</item>
                <item name="template" xsi:type="string">ui/grid/toolbar</item>
            </item>
        </argument>
        <bookmark name="bookmarks" class="\MyVendor\MyModule\Component\Bookmark">
            <argument name="data" xsi:type="array">
                <item name="config" xsi:type="array">
                    <item name="component" xsi:type="string">Magento_Ui/js/grid/controls/bookmarks/bookmarks</item>
                    <item name="storageConfig" xsi:type="array">
                        <item name="saveUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/save"/>
                        <item name="deleteUrl" xsi:type="url" path="mui/bookmark/delete"/>
                        <item name="namespace" xsi:type="string">my_product_listing</item>
                    </item>
                </item>
            </argument>
        </bookmark>
        <columnsControls name="columns_controls"/>
        <filters name="listing_filters" />
        <paging name="listing_paging"/>
    </listingToolbar>
</listing>
```

Replace: `\MyVendor\MyModule` and `my_product_listing` with your namespace.

Also there is another way of add the store selector in the grid i.e via filters same as catalog product grid.

Comment: Also, Do you want to filter products on the basis of the selected store?
Because that's another thing to be done.

Comment: yes i want to do

Comment: @RutveeSojitra  I have updated the code. hope it helps

Comment: Hi @MilindSingh. Can you please update file path in your answer ? It will be helpful for me.

Comment: Hi @DharmikPonda I have updated the paths. Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks !! +1 for update answer. Can you please just tell me. How to set custom collection in prepare function and display in grid when store switcher?

Comment: Hello Milind, I do same things. But, store vise filter can't return. What should I need to do?